# Message delayed by cpu intensive function

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="message"></div>

document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Message Here";
foo();
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
```

Where foo() is a very cpu intensive function. The idea is to display a message while foo() does it's thing, which may take 5 or more seconds. The problem is that the message doesn't get displayed until after foo() is done (I know this because If I don't clear the message, it appears after foo() completes). I know I can do this by delaying foo with a timeout, but for logistical reasons I don't want to do that (this is just an example, the actual code is much more complicated). Why doesn't the innerHTML get set before foo() executes?

Comment: Try converting foo to a promise based function

Comment: Sounds like `foo()` is intensive enough to blocked the renderer from redrawing the element. Wrap it with a promise and the chances are that the renderer will run before your function runs.

Comment: the function returns the result, so using a timeout or promise would require changing the flow, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: Just FYI, the promise didn't work. Same probleem.